# Can I create a list of devices connected to switch using PING or some PING freeware

Tags: networking, windows-xp, ping, switch, scanning

I'm hoping there is a way to list all devices connected to our switch/LAN, **including all devices on different subnets**, using PING command prompt command or some sort of PING freeware.

I connected our phone system to our switch so we can administer it here locally, but I'm not sure of the IP address since if I have things configured correctly, I can't ping the default IP address listed in the manual.

As a side note, the software I found to administer the phone system only runs on Windows XP.  I downloaded/installed Windows Virtual PC and Windows XP from MIcrosoft. If I can determine the IP/subnet of the phone system, hopefully I can configure the virtual machine's Windows XP's IP/subnet correctly in order to connect to/administer phone system.

Comment: I'd give Advanced IP Scanner a go.

Comment: It's not generally safe to assume that any given device will respond to a ping. Many devices and firewalls ignore pings, or can be configured to do so.

Comment: @Fopedush, "It's not generally safe..."  Does that mean it could cause problems if I ping these devices?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: It wouldn't cause a problem per se, but you wouldn't receive a response if a device was set up to ignore pings. That might cause you to think that the device is offline when it actually isn't.